# Change column type from object to float but got TypeError

Tags: python, pandas, data-manipulation

I have a problem on column type.
The column is like:

```
# df
col1
0.7368
0.5
NaT
0.2

print(df.dtypes)
col1   object
```

I want to change `col1` to `float` data type but got `TypeError`.

```
df.col1_new = df.col1.astype(float)

TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NaTType'
```

Do I need to change `NaT` to space? I thought `NaT` should be considered as missing...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with `to_numeric`

```
pd.to_numeric(df.col1,errors='coerce')
Out[33]: 
0    0.7368
1    0.5000
2       NaN
3    0.2000
Name: col1, dtype: float64
```

The problem here is column is str type

```
df.col1.apply(type)
Out[34]: 
0    <class 'str'>
1    <class 'str'>
2    <class 'str'>
3    <class 'str'>
Name: col1, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

You can drop the `NaT` first using `.notnull()`:

```
df.loc[df['b'].notnull(),'b'].astype(float)
```